# Using bash instead of PHP/Perl or Java on server side

Tags: linux, bash, xmlhttprequest, cgi, sh

I am developing a user interface using cgi script and sh and I am having problem in implementing following functionality:

> On clicking a button in browser, an HTTP request should go to a server which
>   should then return a result to the browser.

Problem is that I am going to run this interface in an embedded environment (having httpd as the webserver) where I don't have php, perl or java for server side coding.

I know I can use XMLHttpRequest of javascript but I am not sure if sh can be used to handle those requests on server. Is it? Can I use bash/sh instead of php/java/perl on server side  (for I don't have any of these programing languages on my embedded device) ?

or are there any alternatives to XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: How about CGI using c? http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html#why

Comment: I am not as comfortable with C as I am with bash but still if there is a way to use the 'onclick' event of html button such that on clicking the button a C program on server may get executed, i would like to know about it more. I am already familiar with using the POST method with C and html though.

Comment: Do you have any server-side programming experience?

Comment: :-/ Yes..I have coded in php.

Comment: Then, read about CGI. It sure is more difficult (and cumbersome) than php it isn't that hard.

Comment: It needs to be said that shell script is widely recommended against for CGI because it's hard to avoid security problems. <slur> If your background is with PHP, I guess you don't care, but I certainly hope you're not creating an on-line banking interface.

Comment: recommended or 'not' recommended? No I am not developing anything needing top notch security. I am just trying to develop GUI for some operations which need to be run on a network switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` would run on the client's browser, not on the server.

I would indeed suggest writing in C a CGI which, perhaps by using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), would do the HTTP request

You could write your CGI in `sh` (but I am not sure it would be a good idea in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have use CGI with C by using POST method. But now  want to use the 'onclick' event of html button such that when button is clicked, onClick calls a javascript function which in turn may call a cgi script or c program running on server. Am I thinking in the right direction? Is it possible?

Comment: You don't need `onclick` for that case -you don't even need any javascript, since a `<input type='submit'` is enough. If you wanted fancy AJAXism, you could indeed use `XMLHtmlRequest` in Javascript code.

Comment: Right...'submit' will do but if you have more information about handling XMLHttpRequest in C or bash or server side, I would love to hear about it. Thanks.

Comment: On the server side, you see only HTTP requests... So your `XMLHttpRequest` in Javascript would send `GET` or `POST` requests, which would each trigger their own CGI process.

Answer (score 1):

You can write CGI in anything - including "sh" (if your embedded system has a complete shell), C, Python or Perl (Perl is available for just about *any* platform, isn't it?)

Writing a server side "action" for an HTTP button is standard - any CGI implementation can handle it.

Ajax/XHR?  That's a horse of a different color, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. I have used CGI with bash making use of the POST method. Do you know of a way to use on 'onclick' event of html button such that when it is clicked, a sh script running on server may run which may then return some result too?